# I need admob smart banner to be on bottom of app (using XML if possible)

Tags: java, android, xml, admob

I want to make admob smart banner to be on bottom of app using xml code if possible (without this orange space on the bottom). Btw that orange color is my app background.

Here's my ad in xml:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="@string/ad"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
```

That's how it looks on smartphone
[image]

And that's how it looks in android studio:
[image]

And that's when other ad size is loaded:
[image]

Comment: It is okay as your requirement. Check if it's parent has any padding/margin in bottom.

Comment: @Rasel I've updated the question, there's no padding/margin

Comment: I think your code is okay. May be there is transparent space in bottom of ad itself

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="@string/ad"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
```

and make sure that the parent view height is set to match_parent

Comment: any more info about that ? same problem ?

Comment: I would recommend you to switch to a relative view instead of a constraint view.